# How can I prove that $e^x \cdot e^{-x}=1$ using Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

When proving $e^x.e^{-x}=1$ by using Taylor series, there are infinite many terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Is there any fancy way to combine terms by terms to show that eventually it is equal to $1$?

Comment: It is equivalent to $0=(1-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$ for $n > 0$.

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
e^x\,e^{-x}&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{m+n}}{m!\,n!}\end{align}$$

Now, let $p=m+n$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
e^x\,e^{-x}&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{p=m}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p-m}x^{p}}{m!\,(p-m)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^p\frac{(-1)^{p-m}x^{p}}{m!\,(p-m)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^px^{p}\sum_{m=0}^p\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m!\,(p-m)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^px^{p}}{p!}\sum_{m=0}^p\binom{p}{m}\,(-1)^m\\\\
&=1+\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^px^{p}}{p!}\left(\sum_{m=0}^p\binom{p}{m}\,(-1)^m\right) \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Noting that the binomial expansion of

$$\begin{align}
0&=(1-1)^p\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^p\binom{p}{m}(-1)^m \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ reveals $e^x\,e^{-x}=1$.  And we are done!

Comment: Using exactly the same approach we can prove via binomial theorem that $e^{x}e^{y} = e^{x + y}$. +1

Comment: @paramanandsingh Hello my friend.  And yes, I read your excellent posts on your site where you used various approaches to develop properties of the log and exponential functions.  +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Set $e^x=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$, where $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$.  Similarly, set $e^{-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n x^n$, where $b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$.

By the [usual formula for multiplying power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division), we have $$e^x e^{-x}=\sum_{i\ge 0}c_i x^i$$
where $$c_i=\sum_{j=0}^i a_jb_{i-j}=\sum_{j=0}^i \frac{1}{j!}\frac{(-1)^{i-j}}{(i-j)!}=\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^i(-1)^j{i\choose j}=\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}(1-1)^i=\begin{cases}0&i\ge 1\\1 & i=0\end{cases}$$
Note that $(1-1)^i=\sum_{j=0}^i(-1)^j{i\choose j}$ by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).  In the special case $i=0$, there is just one summand, and that is $1$.

Comment: What does it really mean "i=0" case?

Comment: When we calculate $c_1, c_2, \ldots,$ we can do it with the binomial theorem.  For $c_0$, we get $0^0$, which doesn't make sense.  So we just calculate $\frac{(-1)^0}{0!}\sum_{j=0}^0(-1)^j{0\choose j}=1$.

Comment: Is 0^0 always 1 or is this how we define this for this casE?

Comment: It's often useful to define $0^0=1$, but it is not a universally held definition.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  As per the comments discussion my answer is perhaps not in the spirit of the exercise and my argument can be made cleaner, but I'll keep it as is.

Here is a method which avoids the headache of formulas for multiplying infinte sums.

You could naively compute the Taylor series by computing the derivatives $$ \frac{d^k}{dx^k} e^{x} e^{-x} $$
so for $k=1$ you'd get $$ e^x e^{-x} - e^x e^{-x} =0 $$ for all $x$ and so all the derivatives vanish. Thus the taylor series for the function has only a constant term and thus $e^x e^{-x}$ is constant. If you were then to multiply the Taylor series for each product you'd quickly see that the only way for their product to have a constant term, i.e. a term with no $x^n$ is if you multiplied the constant terms of the two taylor series. Given that both taylor series have constant term $1$ you get the desired result.

Comment: This is nice, but it presupposes knowing the derivatives of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.  If we are trying to prove their product is $1$, we are likely just developing basic properties and haven't determined derivatives yet.

Comment: @vadim123 I suppose that's fair. In the context of an intro calculus course though I'd say this is okay. Maybe we could start from the assumption that $e^x$ is just notation for a solution to the differential equation $\frac{df}{dx} = f$ and then want to determine the property above? That way we are starting with knowledge of derivatives.

Comment: @vadim123 You can determine the derivative of $e^x$ via the Taylor series . The derivative of $e^{-x}$ follows by the chain rule.

Comment: I think derivatives are fair game.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I'm not sure that was what he meant. I think he was intending to say that we only accept the Maclaurin representation of $e^x$ to start with.

Comment: Right, but the Maclaurin representation of $e^x$ lets us figure out the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. @Yeldarbskich

Comment: @Yeldarbskich BTW, if $e^xe^{-x}$ is constant, that constant is $e^0e^{-0}=1$. You don't need any further arguments.

Comment: Sure, so we are replacing the headache of series multiplication with the headache of finding derivatives of series.